# Date parse - Invalid date for some data

Tags: javascript, parsing, date, format

I am looking to parse the below date format in JavaScript but I am struggling to make it work reliably.

```
//Works
var a = new Date("Thu, Nov 7 12:59:45 GMT 2013")
alert(a)
//Invalid date
var b = new Date("Tue, Jun 19 11:14:23 BST 2012")
alert(b)
```

What is a reliable method of parsing this date format?

I am testing in FireFox 36.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the parsing will automatically associate the timezone if I remove it

var b = new Date("Tue, Jun 19 11:14:23 BST 2012".replace("BST",""))

I would prefer it to just work but meh